# How to use TextInputLayout without a TextInputEditText like child?

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

I want to have the same field, like Google Fit:

[image]

So I add a TextInputLayout like that, but I can't setup the editext for hide cursor, hide keyboard:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/TextInputLayoutStyle">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/date"
                style="@style/NewWizardItemPlanTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="none"
                android:hint="@string/date" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Thank you very much for your support guys!

Comment: isn't that a spinner inside?

Comment: Google is likely using a custom View to wrap that spinner.

Answer (score 1):

Add Custom View and adjust as per your needs.!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:background="@color/white"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/border_btn">

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </Spinner>

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Date"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingStart="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingEnd="5dp"
    android:textColor="#4e8cff"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    />
```

border_btn.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<solid android:color="#00000000" />

<stroke
    android:width="3dp"
    android:color="#4e8cff" />

<corners android:radius="5dp" />

</shape>
```

**Output**

[image]